# HAProxy configuration for blocking IPs for sub URLs

Tags: haproxy

I am new to HAProxy. I want to restrict all to access a sub URL but not for access from few IPs.
My Implementation of HAProxy is below and it is not block any IPs/URLs

```
# Listen to port 80.  Throw a 301 redirect to port 443
frontend Listen80
    bind *:80
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }

# List to port 443.  Redirect to appropriate backend based on URL
frontend Listen443
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/examplesslpem %>

    acl web_url        path_beg   /abc /xyz
    acl web_url        path_beg   /efg /xy
    acl batch_url      path_beg   /h /ga
    acl network_allowed  src      example.xyz.com
    acl resticted_pages  path_beg   /abc/qaz/
    http-request allow if resticted_pages network_allowed
    use_backend BATCH        if batch_url
    use_backend SVC          if svc_url
    use_backend WEB          if web_url

    # Listen to port 8080.  Pass through to WEB backend
frontend Listen8080
    bind *:8080
    use_backend WEB

backend WEB
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option httpclose
    cookie SERVERIDWEB insert indirect nocache secure
    option forwardfor
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)abc[/]?(.*)     \1\2
    server app-1 example-app1.com:8080 check cookie app1web
    server app-2 example-app2.com:8080 check cookie app2web
    server app-3 example-app3.com:8080 check cookie app3web
    server app-4 example-app4.com:8080 check cookie app4web
    server app-5 example-app5.com:8080 check cookie app5web
```

Answer (score 2):

This definitely doesn't do what you want.

```
http-request allow if resticted_pages network_allowed
```

Requests are allowed by default.

Note that `http-request allow` is **not** the opposite of `http-request deny`.  Here, `allow` means *do not process any subsequent `http-request` directives, but instead allow this request to proceed as-is*.

It looks like you want to deny if restricted_pages is true and network_allowed is false, and that looks like this:

```
http-request deny if restricted_pages !network_allowed
```

http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#4-http-request

Note also, this also may not do what you intended:

```
acl network_allowed  src      example.xyz.com
```

This will resolve the "example" hostname into an IP address *at startup*.  The ACL will then behave as if you had used that IP address in the configurarion.

Comment: You mentioned that you have this log entry: `Jan 5 21:36:11 localhost.example5dev-lb.com haproxy[20060]: 172.68.xxx.xxx:32455 [05/Jan/2017:21:36:11.492] Listen443~ Listen443/ 0/-1/-1/-1/1 403 188 - - PR-- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /abc/qaz HTTP/1.1"`.  This is from 172.68.xxx.xxx which is not in the `network_allowed` ACL, although that may be because you sanitized it.